# Display values in label from SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to load the values to label from a SQL query:

```
sc.Open();
string type = Vehicle_cost.SelectedText;
string query = ("select Type from Vehicle_Registor where Reg_No = '" + type + "';");

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, sc);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
label23.Text = sdr.ToString();
sc.Close();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Try below code..

```
sc.Open();

string query = @"select Type from Vehicle_Registor where Reg_No = @Reg_No";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, sc);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reg_No", Vehicle_cost.SelectedText);

SqlDataReader sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
sdr.Read();

label23.Text = sdr[0].ToString();

sc.Close();
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, sc);
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            label23.text += sdr[i].ToString();
        }
    }
}
sc.Close();
```

Comment: Handle OP's problems properly while answering. First query itself is subject to **SQLInjection** and why do you think he needs a loop to iterate. One registration per vehicle, concept is simple.

Comment: @AmneshGoel If query returns scalar value maybe it's more reasonable to use `ExecuteScalar`?